# Terminal Server profiles script broken in Powershell 5

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been using the following to set and get terminal server profiles through powershell for years:

```
$user = [ADSI]"LDAP://$dn"
$user.psbase.InvokeGet("terminalservicesprofilepath")
$user.psbase.InvokeSet("terminalservicesprofilepath",'\\server\share\user')
```

Since upgrading to `windows 10` and thus `Powershell 5` this no longer works and produces the following error:

```
 Exception calling "InvokeGet" with "1" argument(s): "Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 
(DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))" At line:1 char:1 + ldap.psbase.invokeget("terminalservicesprofilepath")
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

It seems as if MS have removed these properties, anyone found a way around this?

Comment: I have since noticed that the Remote Desktop tabs are no longer present in the ADUC snap-in in Windows 10. Seems as though this might be "by design"

Comment: I have figured out a workaround, if you copy tsuserex.dll and tsuserex.dll.mui from a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine to the correct location on your Windows 10 machine and register them you can then see the RDS tabs in ADUC and the powershell script works again.